# Hibernate Criteria Restrictions AND / OR combination

Tags: hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria, restrictions

How would I achieve this using Hibernate Restrictions?

```
(((A='X') and (B in('X',Y))) or ((A='Y') and (B='Z')))
```

Answer (score 175, accepted):

think works

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(clazz); 
Criterion rest1= Restrictions.and(Restrictions.eq(A, "X"), 
           Restrictions.in("B", Arrays.asList("X",Y)));
Criterion rest2= Restrictions.and(Restrictions.eq(A, "Y"), 
           Restrictions.eq(B, "Z"));
criteria.add(Restrictions.or(rest1, rest2));
```

Answer (score 3):

For the new Criteria since version Hibernate 5.2:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = getSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<SomeClass> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(SomeClass.class);

Root<SomeClass> root = criteriaQuery.from(SomeClass.class);

Path<Object> expressionA = root.get("A");
Path<Object> expressionB = root.get("B");

Predicate predicateAEqualX = criteriaBuilder.equal(expressionA, "X");
Predicate predicateBInXY = expressionB.in("X",Y);
Predicate predicateLeft = criteriaBuilder.and(predicateAEqualX, predicateBInXY);

Predicate predicateAEqualY = criteriaBuilder.equal(expressionA, Y);
Predicate predicateBEqualZ = criteriaBuilder.equal(expressionB, "Z");
Predicate predicateRight = criteriaBuilder.and(predicateAEqualY, predicateBEqualZ);

Predicate predicateResult = criteriaBuilder.or(predicateLeft, predicateRight);

criteriaQuery
        .select(root)
        .where(predicateResult);

List<SomeClass> list = getSession()
        .createQuery(criteriaQuery)
        .getResultList();
```