# Hibernate Criteria query for Multiple columns in IN clause

Tags: hibernate

I have a table like below
    CODES(location, code, description, start_date, end_date)

I need the below query using Hibernate criteria or detached criteria

SELECT location, code, description, start_date, end_date
  FROM CODES
  WHERE (location,code) in (('loc1','1'),('loc2','2'),('loc3','3'),('loc4','4'),('loc5','5'))

I have to pass the location and code values as parameters(dynamically pass at run time).

How to get the above query using Hibernate criteria or detached criteria

Comment: Please elaborate on what you have tried so far. A piece of code you have tried could also help.

Comment: is there a way in hibernate to achieve the above scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An equivalent expression in SQL is:

```
SELECT location, code, description, start_date, end_date 
FROM CODES 
WHERE (
    (location = 'loc1' AND code = '1') OR
    (location = 'loc2' AND code = '2') OR
    (location = 'loc3' AND code = '3') OR
    (location = 'loc4' AND code = '4') OR
    (location = 'loc5' AND code = '5')
)
```

You can follow [this instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126589/hibernate-criteria-restrictions-and-or-combination) to write the hibernate criteria.