# Hibernate Criteria Query for multiple columns with IN clause and a subselect

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a question very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411894/hibernate-criteria-query-for-multiple-columns-in-in-clause).

I am selecting all data from table1 for all matching unique combinations of field3 and field4 from table2.

Here is my stripped down SQL:

```
select *
from table1 as t1
where (t1.field1, t1.field2) in (select distinct field3, field4
                                 from table2 as t2
                                 where t2.id=12345);
```

I need to translate my SQL to Hibernate Criteria.  I have my entity objects mapping correctly to the tables and transform the response into the correct result entity, but I cannot get my where clause translated correctly.

**What I Have**

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Table1.class);

DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Table2.class);
ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
projectionList.add(Projections.property("field3"), "field3");
projectionList.add(Projections.property("field4"), "field4");
subquery.setProjection(Projections.distinct(projectionList));
subquery.add(Restrictions.eq("id", 12345));
```

I want my where clause to be something like:

```
criteria.add(Subqueries.in("field1, field2", subquery));
```

But that is not allowed by Hibernate.

I have tried rolling out the where clause to have two subqueries and checking both field1 and field2 against the results, but it seems like the subqueries will always have to return multiple columns.  I did this using group by but Hibernate will automatically add the columns in the group by to the projection list and I cannot find a way to remove them.

Here is the same query using group by:

```
select *
from table1 as t1
where t1.field1 in (select field3
                    from table2 as t2
                    where t2.id=12345
                    group by field3, field4)
  and t1.field2 in (select field4
                    from table2 as t2
                    where t2.id=12345
                    group by field3, field4);
```

Is it possible to do my where clause using Hibernate Criteria?

If it is not possible using Hibernate Criteria, is it possible to do my where clause using HQL?

**EDIT:**

@Larry.Z answers my question by using HQL.

I was able to solve my problem with Hibernate Criteria, but I had to modify the query to:

```
select *
from table1 as t1
where exists (select 1
              table2 as t2
              where t2.id=12345
                and t2.field3=t1.field1
                and t2.field4=t1.field2);
```

Translated to Hibernate Criteria:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Table1.class, "t1");

DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Table2.class, "t2");
subquery.add(Restrictions.eq("t2.id", 12345));
subquery.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("t2.field3", "t1.field1"));
subquery.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("t2.field4", "t1.field2"));
subquery.setProjection(Projections.property("t2.id")); // select the ID rather than 1
```

I'm still curious if it is possible to write Hibernate Criteria using my original SQL.

Comment: Restrictions has AND, OR etc., is that what you are looking for?https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html

Comment: No, I don't think so.  I'm trying to write the "IN" clause using tuples in Hibernate Criteria.  It doesn't look like hibernate will let me return a tuple (ex. ['field3', 'field4'] ) from the sub select; nor will it let me compare tuples using "IN".  Alternatively, I tried rolling out my query uding two subqueries,  but Hibernate likes to add the extra columns to the projection.  Look at my first sub query - grouping by field3 and field4 will return both field3 and field4 in the results of the sub query even though I only specify to return field3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to write HQL query like this

```
String hql = "from Table1 t1 where (t1.field1, t1.field2) in (
    select distinct t2.field3, t2.field4
    from Table2 t2
    where t2.id=12345)";
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql).list()
```

Comment: Thanks Larry.Z. For some reason I couldn't get the '(tuple) in (sub select)' to work before.  I would prefer to stick with Hibernate Criteria if possible, but this is a great alternative!

Answer (score 5):

[Subqueries.propertiesIn](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Subqueries.html#propertiesIn(java.lang.String[],%20org.hibernate.criterion.DetachedCriteria)) is what you need:

```
criteria.add(Subqueries.propertiesIn(
                new String[] { "field1", "field2" },
                detachedCriteria));
```