# SQL Multiple Columns in IN clause to convert to JPA

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa, orm

I want to convert/translate the below query with multiple columns in `IN` clause to `JPA`.

**Query:**

```
SELECT city FROM user WHERE (firstName, lastName) IN (('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what JPA is (I can Google it; what I mean is that I am not familiar with it); but: if there is any hope to handle a SQL query, and the only issue is translating a condition on tuples, then rewrite the query like so:

```
select city 
from   user
where  firstname = 'a' and lastname = 'b'
   or  firstname = 'c' and lastname = 'd'
;
```

This is what the query engine will do with your original query regardless; you can look at an EXPLAIN PLAN to convince yourself of this.

Some people like to put parentheses around each pair of `AND`-connected conditions; I don't, any more than I would use parentheses for 2 * 3 + 4 * 6, but if you feel they add clarity, by all means you can add them.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some sort of a subquery, which i think would be more relevant than a set of explicitly defined pairs (you can also stack it up with `or` statements for more complex cases):

```
SELECT city 
FROM user 
WHERE (firstName, lastName) IN (
     select stringOne, stringTwo from TableOne t ...
   )
   or
   (firstName, lastName) IN (
     select stringOne, stringTwo from TableTwo t ...
   )
```

Comment: strinOne and stringTwo are the values which I fetch from the user and I use in the query as a search option. So I guess I cannot get those from Backend table

Comment: in theory you could select literal text.. select 'a', 'b' from Table t.

Comment: shall we write the logic into "select city from user where ((firstName = 'a' and lastName = 'b') or (firstName = 'c' and lastName = 'd'))". Which is more effiecient?

Comment: in the end should be the same thing. If your on oracle you could run some query analysys on each of them and find out