# Restriction.or in Hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql, restriction

I have this select in `SQL`.

How can I convert it to `HQL` using `Restrictions.or` ?

```
select * from users where users.user_type = 1
     or user.id = 1001;
```

`1001` is not of `user_type = 1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126589/hibernate-criteria-restrictions-and-or-combination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this problem by using `Restrictions.disjunction()` and `Restrictions.conjunction()` with Hibernate.