# Hibernate org.hibernate.criterion.Example.create OR clause

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria, query-by-example

I'm using [org.hibernate.criterion.Example.create](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Example.html#create(java.lang.Object)) to create my query from my Entity object. Everything is fine, but using this method the SQL is only created with AND clause between the restrictions.

Is it possible to use [org.hibernate.criterion.Example.create](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Example.html#create(java.lang.Object)) but with OR clause?

Comment: This may be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126589/hibernate-criteria-restrictions-and-or-combination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, you can not do it, but you can implement a `OrExample`, it's pretty easy, only check the source code of the `Example` and change the `and` for `or` (see [sourcecode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate/3.2.7.ga/org/hibernate/criterion/Example.java%20sourecode) line 329). Since the methods are protected, you can extend it and override just the necesary.

Something like this:

```
public class OrExample extends org.hibernate.criterion.Example {

    @Override
    protected void appendPropertyCondition(
        String propertyName,
        Object propertyValue,
        Criteria criteria,
        CriteriaQuery cq,
        StringBuffer buf)
    throws HibernateException {
        Criterion crit;
        if ( propertyValue!=null ) {
            boolean isString = propertyValue instanceof String;
            if ( isLikeEnabled && isString ) {
                crit = new LikeExpression(
                        propertyName,
                        ( String ) propertyValue,
                        matchMode,
                        escapeCharacter,
                        isIgnoreCaseEnabled
                );
            }
            else {
                crit = new SimpleExpression( propertyName, propertyValue, "=", isIgnoreCaseEnabled && isString );
            }
        }
        else {
            crit = new NullExpression(propertyName);
        }
        String critCondition = crit.toSqlString(criteria, cq);
        if ( buf.length()>1 && critCondition.trim().length()>0 ) buf.append(" or ");
        buf.append(critCondition);
    }
```

See the `or` instead of the original `and`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can

```
session.createCriteria(Person.class) .add(Restrictions.disjunction() .add(Restrictions.eq("name", "James")) .add(Restrictions.eq("age", 20)) );
```

In the example above, class Person would have properties name and age and you would be selecting those people with name = "James" or age = 20.

Comment: The question is about using the `Example` class with `or`, not about creating or criterias.

Comment: exactly as @AVolpe said. The question is related to Example.

Answer (score 1):

an old post from SO may be helpful: [Hibernate Criteria Restrictions AND / OR combination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126589/hibernate-criteria-restrictions-and-or-combination)

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(clazz); 
Criterion rest1= Restrictions.and(Restrictions.eq("A", "X"), 
           Restrictions.in("B", Arrays.asList("X","Y")));
Criterion rest2= Restrictions.and(Restrictions.eq("A", "Y"), 
           Restrictions.eq("B", "Z"));
criteria.add(Restrictions.or(rest1, rest2));
```

Comment: The question is about using the `Example` class with `or`, not about creating or criterias.