# Hibernate Criteria filter Entity where ManyToMany relation contains multiple objects

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, criteria

I need help with Hibernate Criteria API.

I have a class Job that contain a list of Skill in ManyToMany relationship.

I need to select jobs based on a skill list given as parameter.

I've tried with `Restriction.in("skill.id",ids)` but this gives me wrong list.If i've selected 2 skills in search form i want the jobs that contain BOTH of them,so i need somehow to implement AND clause.

I've tried with Conjunction:

```
    Conjunction and = Restrictions.conjunction();   
    for(Skill skill:job.getSkills()){
            and.add(Restrictions.eq("skill.id",skill.getId()));
}
```

And this:

```
Criteria crit = criteria.createCriteria("skills",JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
                 for(Skill skill:job.getSkills()){
                     crit.add(Restrictions.eq("id", skill.getId()));
                 }
```

but it creates same alias for skill and it gives me no result.
sql is `and (skill1_.ID=? and skill1_.ID=?)`

Can anyone help me with this ?thanks

**UPDATE:**

HQL Query will be like:

```
select a from Job a where exists (select skill1.id from Skill skill1 join skill1.jobs r where r.id=a.id and skill1.id=1) and exists (select skill2.id from Skill skill2 join skill2.jobs r where r.id=a.id and skill2.id=4)
```

I need Criteria based on this.

Comment: what about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126589/hibernate-criteria-restrictions-and-or-combination

Answer (score 1):

```
for(Skill skill:job.getSkills()){
                    DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Skill.class,"skill");
                    subquery.add(Restrictions.eq("id",skill.getId()));
                    subquery.setProjection(Projections.property("id"));
                    subquery.createAlias("jobs", "job");
                    subquery.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("job.id", "Job.id"));
                    criteria.add(Subqueries.exists(subquery));  
                }
```

I managed to solve it.now it works perfect.