# Hibernate 'AND' and 'OR' using Criteria for preexisting criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have an existing criteria to which I want to add one more criterion that ORs with the preexisting criteria. I'd like to add that I cannot control how the preexisting criteria is constructed.

For eg: 
My preexisting criteria translates to the following SQL:
select * from users where status = 'ACTIVE' and acctId = xyz

I want to add a criterion which would change this query to 
select * from users where (status = 'ACTIVE' and acctId = xyz) or deptId = abc.

I am unable to find a way to modify the exitsing criteria to become part of a disjunction.

My object looks like:
`User{Long userId, String status, Long acctId, Long deptId}`

Any pointers appreciated.

Thanks,
W

Comment: I guess you need to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126589/hibernate-criteria-restrictions-and-or-combination

Comment: Like i mentioned - i donot have control over the created criteria. My problem is i need to either modify an existing criteria or get criterions from the preexisting criteria to create my own criteria - both of which i am unable to find a way to do.

Comment: I can haz code being used pls? :)